# I am being notified that an error occurred in the system. How do I solve this problem?

Tags: python3, gtk

This is my first post I don't know how to format this code. I am sorry.

```
eskisadi@eskisadi:~$ ls -l /var/crash/
total 5648
-rw-r----- 1 root     whoopsie 5536768 Tem 16 22:48 _usr_bin_python3.8.0.crash
-rw-r----- 1 eskisadi whoopsie  239030 Tem 16 19:09 _usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r-- 1 eskisadi whoopsie       0 Tem 16 19:09 _usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Tem 16 19:13 _usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.1000.uploaded
```

Comment: There is no actual question in your question description (some browsers & devices don't display heading when page is opened..), but you `ubuntu-bug [filename]` where [filename] is the name of the .crash file you are reporting - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 0):

If you agreed to send the error report, then you have already reported the bug and your part in the process is done.

Depending upon how many similar reports are received, a community volunteer or Canonical engineer will try to reproduce the crash, troubleshoot the problem, and the fix may appear in a future release of Ubuntu. Crashes are considered bugs to be investigated and fixed, not features to be disabled or worked around.

- Your crash report is anonymous. It contains no personal information, nor any way to contact you. If you are willing to help provide additional information and help test patches, open a bug report against the relevant package (`ubuntu-bug packge_name`) and attach the .crash file.
- Crashes that cannot be reliably reproduced in a test environment generally cannot be fixed.
- Be patient. Some easy, high-priority bugs can be fixed in a few days. Others that are more complex or low-priority or involve multiple upstream developers may languish. You can increase the speed of a fix with a really useful bug report that explains clearly how to reproduce the problem in a test environment in the fewest steps.
- It's unlikely that an unskilled user can solve the crash. Feel free to try, though: Everything you need is in that crash report.